# How can I modify this regex pattern so that once it finds a match it returns the whole sentence, not just the words it matched?

Tags: python, regex

As the title explains this regex pattern basically checks the description variable for matching word combinations within set, eg:

```
set = ["oak", "wood"]
```

then if it finds those 2 words within a 5 word spacing it will return those words. However, I need it to return the matching sentence. So if for example the description was:

```
description = "...would be a lovely addition to any home. This lovely oak hard wood table comes in a variety of sizes. Another great reason to consider..."
```

instead of just returning the matching words I want it to return the entire sentence that contains the keywords.

This is what I'm working with at the moment which obviously just returns the matching set pair.

```
re.findall(r"\b(?:(%s)\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,5}?(%s)|(%s)\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,5}?(%s))\b" % (set[0], set[1], set[1], set[0]), description)
```

I'm also aware that I believe this pattern will look beyond a single sentence for a match and as such you might get a case where it finds a match over 2 different sentences. If possible I'd also like to find a way that restricts matches to only be possible within the same sentence.

I'd appreciate any help I can get with this.

EDIT: Just to clarify my desired output is:

```
"This lovely oak hard wood table comes in a variety of sizes."
```

As this is the sentence which contains the matching keyword pair.

Thanks!

Comment: @KyleA can I just say how much I appreciate you saying that. I literally never ask anything on StackOverflow because of the attitude and mentality of some people on here. I have spent hours making sure nothing like this has been posted so I don't offend anyone and then made sure the question is as concise and well explained as possible.

Comment: I'd rather go a different way: split the sentences first (using e.g. [**`nltk`**](https://www.nltk.org/), look for `sent_tokenize()`) and search your words in every sentence.

Comment: Is the order is important? You pass 4 words and you find a sentence with those 4 words at any place. Or they must appear in order?

Comment: @Julio the keyword pair's order is not important however to avoid false positives their proximity is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my comment some dummy code using `nltk` (do not have access to `Python` right now):

```
from nltk import sent_tokenize

for sent in sent_tokenize(your_data_here):
    if any(['foo', 'bar']) in sent:
        # do sth. useful here
```

Obviously, you could even apply your initial regex on `sent` (it's a string after all).

Comment: I like this approach. I was unaware the sentence tokenizer existed.

Comment: @KyleA: The tokenizer takes other punctuation into account as well (like `?`, `!`, `:`, etc.). Why reinvent the wheel...

Comment: I believe this is what I'm looking for as the initial regex would still be very necessary because the proximity detection is required due to the possibility of false positives in longer descriptions eg: "This is NOT oak however we do make other varieties that use cherry for a different style of hard wood" - without proximity being checked this would obviously still return True as "oak" and "wood" are still present. I'll give it a go including the regex and mark as solved once I can confirm. Thanks :)

Comment: @Jan awesome solution mate.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following RegEx:

```
print(re.findall(r"(^|(?<=\.))([a-zA-Z0-9\s]*oak[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*wood.*?(?=\.|$)).*?|([a-zA-Z0-9\s]*wood[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*oak.*?(?=\.|$))", description))
```

where:

```
r"(^|(?<=\.))" # means start with 'start of string' or '.'
r"([a-zA-Z0-9\s]*oak[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*wood.*?(?=\.)).*?" # means any letter/number/space followed bi 'oak', followed by any letter/number/space, followed by wood, stopping at the first occurrence of a '.' or 'end of line'
r"([a-zA-Z0-9\s]*wood[a-zA-Z0-9\s]*oak.*?(?=\.|$))" # same as previous, but with | (or) condition matches the wood-oak case
```

**Output:**

> ('', ' This lovely oak hard wood table comes in a variety of sizes',
>   '')

Comment: Hi mate, thanks very much for your input here. Just reading the output I think you may of slightly misunderstood what I'm looking for here, maybe I didn't explain it correctly and will add my desired output in the OP but I'd just be looking to get back "This lovely oak hard wood table comes in a variety of sizes." as this is the sentence containing the matching keyword pair :)

Comment: ok, sorry. so it should contain both the elements, and "sentence" is defined from `.` or start of string to `.` or `\n` or end of string

Comment: This doesn't do what the questioner wants as it returns all the text not the text for the sentence that contains the words

Comment: @JGNI I'm reworking my answer. If you read the comments before yours, you'll get that there was a misunderstanding

Comment: @Gsk OK in that case ignore my comment above

Comment: @gsk sorry, fixed :-)

Answer (score 1):

Is it a must to use regex? I found it more strict forward to just use the below:

```
set = ["oak","wood"]
description = "...would be a lovely addition to any home. This lovely oak hard wood table comes in a variety of sizes. Another great reason to consider..."

description2 = "...would be a lovely addition to any home. This is NOT oak however we do make other varieties that use cherry for a different style of hard wood."

def test_result(desc):
    desc = desc.split(". ")
    for sent in desc:
        if all(s in sent for s in set):
            if -5 <= sent.split(" ").index("oak") - sent.split(" ").index("wood") <= 5:
                print (sent)

test_result(description)
test_result(description2)
```

Result:

```
This lovely oak hard wood table comes in a variety of sizes
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try with following regex:

`[^.]*?\boak(?:\W+[^\W.]+){0,5}?\W+wood(?:\W+[^\W.]+){0,5}?\W+table(?:\W+[^\W.]+){0,5}?\W+variety[^.]*\.+`

**[Demo with several examples](https://regex101.com/r/DQEaL8/1/)**

**Explained:**

```
[^.]*?                 # Anything but a dot, ungreedy
  \b oak               # First word (with word boundary)
(?:\W+[^\W.]+){0,5}?   # Some (0-5) random words: (separator + word except dot) x 5, ungreedy
 \W+ wood              # Second word. Starts with some separator
(?:\W+[^\W.]+){0,5}?   # Again, random words, ungreedy
 \W+ table             # third word. Starts with some separator
(?:\W+[^\W.]+){0,5}?   # Again, random words, ungreedy
 \W+ variety           # Final required word
[^.]*                  # The rest of the sentence (non dot characters) up to the end
\.+                    # We match the final dot (or ... if more exist)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it to capture the entire sentence by having it look for periods at the ends. You can also have it exclude periods from the search in the middle by replacing `\W` (match non-word characters) with `[^.\w]` (match anything that isn't a period or a word character).

`"(^|\.)([^.]*\b(?:(%s)[^.\w]+(?:\w+[^.\w]+){0,5}?(%s)|(%s)[^.\w]+(?:\w+[^.\w]+){0,5}?(%s))\b[^.]*)(\.|$)"`

The `(^|\.)` will match the beginning of the input or a period and the `(\.|$)` will match a period or the end of the input (in case there is input after the last period).

I can't test this in python right now, but it should point you in the right direction even if I have an error or typo.

Comment: How does that handle 5.67 or an IP address or even Mr., Miss., Dr., Prof. etc.

Comment: @JGNI, It will split the sentence at the period. I assumed that the sentences don't have periods in them. Excluding the periods from the middle is optional, but the OP asked if searching across sentence boundaries could be prevented. If you need smarter detection of a sentence boundary, then RegEx is probably the wrong tool, because that becomes a very difficult thing to detect.